# HTML data attribute IE6 support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-6, custom-data-attribute

Does HTML's data attribute work in IE6?

I'm using the attribute like this `<img id="charm_1" data-code='sdfsdfsdfsdf' data-price='100' class='addition_image' src="img/misc/donut.png" width="55" height="55" alt="Donut">`.

As you can see there are 2 data attributes (price and code). I can get this with jQuery using the `.data()` method and it all seems to work in IE7/8/9. Does this work in IE6? I don't have a copy of IE6 to test this.

Comment: Yes. It works just as it does in any other browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE6 -- and indeed all other browsers on the market -- have always been perfectly happy for you to define your own custom attributes on an element.

The use of `data-` as a prefix was formalised in the HTML5 standard, but browsers have always supported it, and don't even really require the `data-` prefix.

The `data-` prefix is recommended because it is now part of the standard, so there's a chance that a future browser may be more picky about it, and also because of the new `dataset` property that was added to HTML5 DOM specification at the same time to support it.

Obviously you can't use the `dataset` property, as very few browsers support it (not even newer ones, let alone older ones), but you can of course always use the good old `getAttribute()` method instead (which is what jQuery does).

To find out about browser support for new properties, I recommend the CanIUse.com site. For example, here is their page about `data-` attributes: http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset. They have full browser support tables for a wide range of features.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IETester](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/IETester-Download-101019.html) in order to test your websites on the different versions of IE and yes it those work on IE6 , IE has supported `getAttribute()` from IE4 which is what jQuery uses internally for `data()`.