# Selecting a new value in a dropdown list while remembering the old value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I'm working on a webshop where customers can choose an amount of items to purchase via a drop down list. Each item have a point value and I calculate the total of their purchase via jQuery (`onChange` event):

```
function showPoints(itemPointValue, ddlAmount){
    var customerPoints = parseInt($('p#points').html());
    currentPoints = customerPoints - (ddlAmount * itemPointValue);
    $('p#points').html(currentPoints);
}//showPoints
```

The only problem here is if they change their amount from say 5 to 4, another 4 * the point value gets taken off their "total points". Their total points ends up becoming totally inaccurate and they can even go below 0. I thought of using `jquery.data` to set an "oldValue" variable but IE does not support this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't find anywhere in jquery docs that .data() don't work in IE, have you tried it? it should work..

Comment: Netbeans IDE tells me:
This function is not supported by the following of your targeted browsers:
Internet Explorer 5.5

I know it seems a bit ridic that i'm worried about 5.5 but I'd like it to work in all browsers

Comment: `jQuery.data` is supported from IE6+ (even though `data` attributes are not supported on IE6 -> they are emulated via some internal arrays). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7846668/1127669).

Comment: I have to ask why you need to support such an old browser? jQuery has known issues with IE < 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using two events on my drop down lists. onClick to save the old data using jquery.data and onChange to check the old value against the new value. If the new value is smaller then the old value I adjust the point total accordingly.

HTML:

```
<select name="dropdown onClick="saveOld(this.value, this.name)" onchange="showPoints(points, this.value,this.name)">
```

JS/Jquery

```
function showPoints(pointCategory, ddlAmount, name){
    old = jQuery.data(document.body,name);
    var Points = parseInt($('p#points').html());
    if(old > ddlAmount){
       diff =  old - ddlAmount;
       currentPoints = Points + (diff * pointCategory);
    }else{
       currentPoints = Points - (ddlAmount * pointCategory);
    }
    $('p#points').html(currentPoints);
}//showPoints

function saveOld(oldAmount, name){
    $(document.body).data(name,oldAmount);
}//saveOld
```

Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

You could store the previous value on a custom attribute as stated above, and you could use the focus event to set the old value, something in the lines of this should work:

```
$('p#points').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).attr('old-value', $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: this is most likely a viable answer so +1. I did go for an alternative approach though.

Comment: for the sake of having it out here, could you specify what that approach was?

Comment: @Alexenadru Bularca my solution is posted below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why not just recalculate the total point cost any time any dropdown is changed, and re-calculate currentPoints by subtracting the new total from customerPoints? This, to me, seems like a much cleaner solution than adding and subtracting values

Comment: I have multipe drop downs and not all are used. I would have to make a function that iterates over all the drops down (which have unique dynamic names involving product ID's) and also checks to see if they're 0 or not. Not to mention different drop down products have different point categories.

Answer (score 0):

How about, creating custom attribute on the element:

`$('p#points').attr('old-value',5);`

and retrieve it like this:

`$('p#points').attr('old-value');`

Comment: This seems like a good idea but since I'm using an onchange event won't the select already be changed to 4 when the event to save the old value fires?

Comment: Can you add handler on mouse hover event of the select element, to save the old value(I know it is not elegant), so just before the value change the old one will be saved